# How to get pointer to first arg of function?

Tags: c++, memory, reflection, stack, unreal-engine4

I want to reflective call function with same arguments without manually coping params (for future this will be macro and this will be automatically).

```
UFUNCTION()
void PleaseRespawnMe(FName className)
{
    uint64 _frame;  // Here is stack pointer?

    UFunction* func = GetController()->ServerCheatManager->FindFunction("PleaseRespawnMe");  // function with same name
    void* startStack = (void*)(&_frame - func->ParmsSize);  // Start stack is pointer to first variable minus params size?
    GetController()->ServerCheatManager->ProcessEvent(func, startStack);  // calling using pointer of first argument
}
```

But `&_frame` pointer is too far from `&className`. Is there solutions to get pointer of args using address of local variable?

P.S. This is Unreal Engine 4 framework (calling function by name is unreal reflection system).

Comment: `without manually coping params` How about passing references instead?

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall but how to get reference without using this parameter name in code? In the future macro I need to reduce any direct handling to parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the codes by searching `FindFunction(` and found this: `for (TFieldIterator<UProperty>`, I think this is what you want.

I tested it with my `UFUNCTION` and the iterators run through the input parameters then the return value.

I suggest that to search `for (TFieldIterator<UProperty>` or `for (TFieldIterator<UProperty> It(Function);` to see the use cases, and note the property flags, which could help with filtering specific properties you are looking for.

Comment: It's reflection data of function's parameters (UProperties), it contains no any actual data of current passed into this function parameters.

I need get function parameters address (start), such as ellipsis (`...` - `void func(uint8 param, ...);`) can be got by address of previous variable in arguments list.

Comment: So is the `void* startStack` being the first arg of the function? I'm not very sure which one is the argument you were trying to pass into `UFunction* func`.

Comment: I found an example function `static void Call(UObject* Target, const TCHAR* FunctionName, void* Args = nullptr)`, is this what you're trying to do?

Comment: `UObject::ProcessEvent(UFunction* Func, void* Parms);` calls the `UFUNCTION` in some context. And `Parms` - is pointer to first parameter in memory. For example I can make `struct { int32 parm1 = 0; FString parm2 = "Hi" } data;` and call the `ProcessEvent(func, &data);`.

So. Function args has same memory representation. And it well be nice to be used identically.

Or I'm wrong?